# Using event emit i want to pass a service data from component A to B

Tags: angular

Problem Statement-
I have a service, Component A and Component B. In the service i am calling my Git Api to get the User in setApi method. i am setting username here from Component A on click of button. In component B i want some details to print by calling the Same service getAPi Method.

My Approach-
I am able to do it with one component but when i am doing it with two component i am not able to call the service same same object . SO i want to do it with Event Emit. I am very new to angular i am not getting how to use Event Emit.

here User is the class i am fetching data in so do not get confuse.

I want to do from  Component A i want to send username and in Component B on click of Component A button method I want that data to be print in Component B Html.

Can anyone tell me to validate not null Component A textbox using reactive form approach also.

Service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GituserdetailsService {
   username:String;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
setApi(username:String)
{
this.username=username;
console.log(this.username);
}

getApi():Observable<any>
{
  console.log(`http://api.github.com/users/`+this.username);
  return this.http.get(`http://api.github.com/users/`+this.username);

}

    /*searchUser(username:String) :Observable<any>
   {
     console.log(`http://api.github.com/users/`+username);
    return this.http.get(`http://api.github.com/users/`+username)    
}*/

}
```

Component A userDetails.ts

```
import { GituserdetailsService } from '../service/gituserdetails.service';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { DetailsComponent } from '../details/details.component';
import { User } from '../user';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup , FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userdetails',
  templateUrl: './userdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userdetails.component.css']
})

export class UserdetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
formSubmitted = false;
errorMessage:any;
username:string ;
details:any;
user:any=new User;
  constructor(private GituserdetailsService:GituserdetailsService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      username:[null,[Validators.required]]
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

    //this.searchUserDetails();

  }
searchUserDetails() :void{ 
  this.details = [];
  this.GituserdetailsService.setApi(this.username);

  //console.log(this.username);

}
}
```

Component B details.ts

```
import { GituserdetailsService } from '../service/gituserdetails.service';
import { UserdetailsComponent } from '../userdetails/userdetails.component';
import { User } from '../user';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})

export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage:any;
  username:string ;
  user:any=new User;

  constructor(private GituserdetailsService:GituserdetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  searchUserDetails() :void{ 
    this.GituserdetailsService.getApi().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      this.user = data; 
      console.log(this.user);   
    },error=>{
      this.errorMessage=error.statusText;
      alert(this.errorMessage);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Subjects`

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GituserdetailsService {
  searchUserDetails = new EventEmitter<void>();
....
```

Component A:

```
...
searchUserDetails() :void{ 
  this.details = [];
  this.GituserdetailsService.setApi(this.username);
// we call next to trip the subscribers
  this.GituserdetailsService.searchUserDetails.emit();
  //console.log(this.username);

}
...
```

Component B:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
.....
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.listenToSearchUserDetails();
  }

  listenToSearchUserDetails() {
    this.GituserdetailsService.searchUserDetails.pipe(
      // once searchUserDetails emits, switch it over to API call
      switchMap(_ => this.GituserdetailsService.getApi()),
    ).subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      this.user = data; 
      console.log(this.user);   
    },error=>{
      this.errorMessage=error.statusText;
      alert(this.errorMessage);
    });
  }
```

As far as the textbox being required, I think `Validators.required` is good enough. What you can do then is check for `this.form.valid` => if it is true, proceed, if not, don't allow operation.

Comment: i want to do it only with emit event

Comment: Subject is the same as an event emitter for me but check out the edit, I think that should work.\